# How to alter result of callback/promise function?

Tags: javascript

I have a function that can return result in both callback and promise:

```
function foo(args, cb) {
  // do stuff
  const promise = getSomePromise();

  if (cb) {
    promise.then((result) => {
      cb(null, result);
    }, (err) => {
      cb(err);
    });
  } else {
    return promise;
  }
}
```

I want to alter the result of `promise` before returning it. How to do this in a way that introduces the least amount of spaghetti code?

Comment: You mean you don't want to alter the result for the callback?

Comment: Btw, if you want to decrease the amount of spaghetti code, then don't write functions that can take an optional callback and conditionally return a promise or not. Just always return promises, and use an additional glue helper function should you need to interface with callback-based code.

Comment: How, exactly, do you want to alter the result of `promise`? You can only chain `catch`/`finally`/`then` off it it.

Comment: @Bergi I want to do a pull request to code that does that. I don't want to alter their code style, just contribute some functionality.

Comment: @chipit24 I want to add a new property to returned object.

Comment: @Poma Either way, just use `.then(…)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a  function to alter and return modified result

```
function alterResult(result){
   const alteredResult = /// do something to result
   return alteredResult;
}
```

Then add it in a `then()`to:

```
const promise = getSomePromise().then(alterResult);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function which returns something and pass it to the callback when initiating it like this

```js
function foo(cb) {
  const promise = getSomePromise(); // return some promise
  promise.then((result) => { // result is here just "Hello"
    cb(doSomething(result)); // return the altered value here to the callback
  })
}

function getSomePromise() {
   return new Promise((resolve, _) => resolve("Hello")) // make a new promise
}
function doSomething(res) { // define a function that alters your result
  return res + ", World"
}
foo((val) => console.log(val)) // log it
```